# Is it okay, when I have no diff between sklearn function and mine?

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

```
def mean_square_error_func(x, y):

  mean_x = x.sum()/len(x)
  mean_y = y.sum()/len(x)
  a2 = np.dot(x.T, x)/len(x)
  a11 = np.dot(x.T, y)/len(x)
 
def mae(pred, true):
    err = np.average(np.abs(pred - true))
    return np.average(err)
def mse(pred, true):
  err = np.average((true - pred) ** 2)
  return np.average(err)  

w = (a11 - mean_x*mean_y)/(a2 - mean_x**2)
  b = mean_y - w*mean_x 
  return w[0][0], b[0][0]
def mae(pred, true):
    err = np.average(np.abs(pred - true))
    return np.average(err)
```

and we have output with same amount in sklearn and our function,

```
Our function W: 9.225266215427487 | B: -6.167292747380287
   SKLEARN function W: 9.225266215427487 | B: -6.167292747380287
   [8.80255752]
   34.54964962288203
   134.97234540746328
   1785.1945144494548
```

is it okay, or I've got some issues with the code?

Comment: The code above looks wonky, maybe resulting from two different pastes.  Your definitions of mae and mse seem reasonable, and full-precision agreement from sklearn is pretty solid validation.

Comment: the mean_square_error function doesn't return anything.  UPDATE: aah i see, mae() and mse() were pasted in the center of the definition of mean_square_error_func